# How to solve the inrush current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, inrush-current

I want to solve the following inrush current (DC):

[image]

There is a switch, which will be closed at time t_0. So that I can redraw the graph.

I want to calculate something like that [Example](http://www.physik.uzh.ch/~strauman/physik-a/Ergaenzung_Stromkreise.pdf). But I do not know, how to set up the equations. for R_3 and L. Does anybody can give me a hint?

Comment: Inrush or incrush?

Comment: Are you allowed to use an NTC?

Comment: How did you get from the original diagram to the redrawn one (after closing the switch)? It's ok, but out of curiosity I'd like to know how you get there (and what is \$U_q\$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the switch closes, the steady state voltage across the inductor is zero, i.e. U_L(0-)=0. Ohm's law tells you that I_R3=0 since it has the same voltage U_L. So I_L(0-) is simply I_q. This is the initial condition.

Your second schematic shows a set up after the switch is closed. One approach would be to simplify the schematic further by translating the voltage source U_q and the 3 resistors to the Thevenin equivalent. If you have done that, you get a simple series voltage-source, resistor and inductor circuit in a loop. The would look exactly like the circuit inside the Example linked, after the switch is closed.

The Example linked has a initial condition of I_L(0)=0. Remember that for this actual circuit, the initial condition is I_L(0)=I_q, use this to solve for the integration constant ("A" in the Example).